# 'LPVOID': illegal use of this type as an expression

Tags: c++, dll

I don't know the very vell the Dynamic-Link-Library if i ask the bad question sorry guys

Im taking the -> 'LPVOID': illegal use of this type as an expression

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
```

Library

```cpp
HANDLE handle;
HWND hwnd;
DWORD pID;
```

Some requires for giving the handle game

```cpp
template <class T>
T Read(DWORD address)
{
    T VALUE;
    ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID), &VALUE, sizeof(T), 0);
    return VALUE;
}
```

RPM Template

```cpp
void readingvariables()
{
    // 00DB0000 - sauerbraten.exe
    DWORD localplayer = Read<DWORD>(0x00DB0000 + 0x213EA8);
    int health = Read<int>(localplayer + 0x15C);
    printf("Health :", health);
}
```

Reading variables there is here

```cpp
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        readingvariables();
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Last here to attach dll

Okey guys im waiting answer have good day :)

Comment: You might want to use nullptr or NULL instead (or something like `(LPVOID)0` )

Comment: What does `(LPVOID), &VALUE` mean? Did you mean to write `(LPVOID) &VALUE`?

Comment: I did this just to read the values, I didn't use what I used in the RPM function, like WPM, I never actually print the value and

Thanks KIIV you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `ReadProcessMemory()` correctly.  You are passing it a type where a memory address is expected. You are ignoring the `address` parameter being passed in to `Read()`, that is what you should be type casting to `LPVOID`, eg:

```cpp
template <class T>
T Read(DWORD address)
{
    T VALUE;
    if (!ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)address, &VALUE, sizeof(T), NULL))
    {
        // error handling...
    }
    return VALUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help i understand a more logic
i don't know the english very well sometimes i can stuck the some errors

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is here:

`ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID), &VALUE, sizeof(T), 0);`

The second argument is just `(LPVOID)`, which is just a type, but it needs to be an expression.  Are you trying to cast something to `LPVOID`?

Perhaps you meant `(LPVOID)&VALUE` or maybe `(LPVOID)0`?

The error message issued to you by your compiler should have given you this line number.

Comment: Thanks dude for logic and answering the question